# Error with git push using new personal access token

Tags: github, token, personal-access-token

I am unable to push to git after generating a new personal access token. I've looked around at similar questions but think that I may have a more fundamental misunderstanding of how this works.

I got an email saying passwords were being phased out, so I generate a token and could no longer push a repo I've been working on using my password. From the instructions it looked like I can use the token just like a password, but to no avail. This is what the error looks like:

[image]

where I have pasted my token when prompted for password. (I've blacked out my username.) I am on Windows 10 and having checked my credentials manager do not appear to have credentials stored for github at the moment.

My questions are:

1. Ideas for immediate convenient fixes? I was seeing some suggestions about setting the remote-url, but a little concerned about doing this for every repo I have. I'd like to change my workflow minimally, if possible.
2. I'm probably grossly misunderstanding the point of the token. What is the "correct" way to set up a workflow to github? (Including maybe big changes that might take me a weekend to set up correctly, in a few weeks from now, say.) Am I supposed to set up a 2FA? (Will this change my web login at all?) Why is this more secure than a password? I've currently not setup SSH or anything else, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed a similar workflow, generating a new token (in [`github.com/settings/tokens`](https://github.com/settings/tokens)), and using it as password without issues.

I just made sure:

- [its scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) included repo, workflow, gist and user. (you can update those scopes without regenerating the token)
- its expiration date was either not set, or set to a date far enough to allow me to test/use it.

The resulting token should start with `ghp_`

```
ghp_DUvWjre....(ghp_ followed by 36 alphanumerical chars)
```

The [OP Tommy Tang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16768541/tommy-tang) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352382/error-with-git-push-using-new-personal-access-token/69357085#comment122661455_69357085):

> I didn't find a previous credential, so I just added a generic credential on the manager, and it works.

---

[punsoca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5109125/punsoca) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352382/error-with-git-push-using-new-personal-access-token/69357085#comment137494186_69357085):

> Originally, I only selected the '`repo`' scope and I followed your tip and added the '`workflow`', '`gist`', and '`user`' scopes.
>
> Speaking of '`user`' scope, everyone should make sure their `user.email` git setting is set as well.
> When Git detects that you changed your Personal Acccess Token (PAT), it will prompt you for a new password - just use the newly generated PAT and it will work!

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and changed the scope and ensured the expiration date was far into the future. But I still get the same error message. Persisted even after I generated a new token and repeated everything. Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Comment: @TommyTang Then check what `git config credential.helper` returns, and double-check (again) your Windows Credential Manager: something is caching, and providing the wrong password

Comment: Hmm, I didn't find a previous credential, so I just added a generic credential on the manager and it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TommyTang Perfect, well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I've generated a personal access token several times, and whenever I try to use it like this I get the same error.

Comment: tensorflow-towardsdatascience git:(master) ✗ git push --set-upstream origin master

Comment: remote: Permission to pdxrod/tensorflow-towardsdatascience.git denied to pdxrod.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pdxrod/tensorflow-towardsdatascience.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: This is after using the technique of changing .git/config to contain url = https://pdxrod:ghp_Xyzetc@github.com/pdxrod/tensorflow-towardsdatascience.git

Comment: @rodmclaughlin Did Git ask you for a password when you pushed, or did it immediately gave you the 403 error message?

Comment: It immediately gave me the 403 error message. However, I have found the solution. You have to click on 'repo' in the Access Token page on Github: https://mycyberuniverse.com/how-fix-fatal-authentication-failed-for-https-github-com.html

Comment: @rodmclaughlin I do mention the repo scope though. Thank you to explain how to select said repo scope.

Comment: It also happens when git is not updated to latest version, run cmd and type `git update-git-for-windows`

Comment: Thank you!  found this tip over 2 years later :D   Oringinally I only selected the 'repo' scope and I followed your tip and added the 'workflow', 'gist', and 'user' scopes.    Speaking of 'user' scope,  everyone should make sure their user.mail git setting is set as well.       When git detects that you change your Personal Acccess Token (PAT), it will prompy you for a new password - just use the newly generated  PAT and it will work!

Comment: @punsoca Thank you for your feedback. I have included part of your comments in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

https://mycyberuniverse.com/how-fix-fatal-authentication-failed-for-https-github-com.html

After generating a new Personal Access Token, under 'Select Scopes', click on 'repo', then hit 'Generate new token'. This will give you a token which can be used to push code from the command line.